# Bitmapdata/bytearray to video file

Tags: actionscript-3, format, flash-cs6

I just started working with Adobe Flash CS6, and have been trying to find a way to make a game that can record parts of itself. So far I have been able to capture the desired areas of the screen as bitmapData and encode that as PNG and JPEG to byte arrays, and have made an array that I use to store them in order of occurrence. I can use file reference to save them to my computer one at a time, but I need a way to group them together as a video file of any sort. Even as a GIF would do, it may not be video but at least it moves.

Basically I have a bunch of frames collected by my game, how do I get them to someone's desktop as a video file?

If this is impossible for Flash CS6, can it be done with Flash Builder or do I need Adobe Air? I have found multiple methods that work for Air, but I don't have it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much answering your own question: you have to encode the data in the right way. Intead of encoding as PNG or JPEG, encode into the video codes that you want.

Comment: I more meant is there a specific code that can do that? But thanks for answering, I'll start looking for how to encode.